# How can a poor connection be treated as no connection when reading Firestore data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I noticed that the Firestore read takes longer time if the connectivity signal is low. It works totally fine if I am in stable network. My apps are actively used by users and each read operation is very important to be fast, no matter it came from server (if device is online) or cache (if device is offline).

My current code is below, which takes around 5 seconds for data to be received if the signal is low:

```
final snapshot = await docData.get();
```

What I want to achieve is to treat low connection as offline, without letting Firestore to try reading the data.

I got this warning log from vscode debug console which came from Firestore, and I would like to catch it if possible:

> W/Firestore(xxxxx): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

By catching the warning log, I should be able to get assumption of current signal and do the logic as the code below.

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot;

if(connectivityStable){
  snapshot = await docData.get();
}else{
  try{
    snapshot = await docData.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
  }catch(e){
            
  }
}
```

**Update**

It's impossible to catch the warning log as mentioned by
@Doug Stevenson , so I will handle it by utilize the `onTimeout` action.

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot;
snapshot = await docData.get().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2),onTimeout: (){
    try{
      return docData.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
    }catch(e){
      return snapshot;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't catch that. It's a warning, not an error.  Note the "W" at the front of the message.  Firestore internally retries all database access so you don't see errors like this coming from the API - the request just eventually succeeds when the network becomes available again.

Comment: @Haizad Annuar if that solved your issue can you or Doug stevenson post it as answer so other community members will also get the answer for this question.

Comment: @RohitKharche I've edited the question, and post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to catch the warning log. Instead, I will handle it by utilize the onTimeout action as for now.

If the source future does not complete before 2 seconds has passed, the [onTimeout] action is executed. More info on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/timeout.html

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot;
snapshot = await docData.get().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2),onTimeout: (){
    try{
      return docData.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
    }catch(e){
      return snapshot;
    }
});
```